# Angular 2: Template not updating after http service update

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I'm still trying to learn ng2 so I'm sure this is a common noob problem but none of the solutions I found online helped. anyone know what my problem is?

I have a service with the getEventList() method as an observable

```
getEventList(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./assets/data.json')
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

I subscribe to it in my component

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.eventService.getEventList()
        .subscribe(events => {
            this.zone.run(()=>{
                this.events = events;
                console.log(this.events)
            });
        });
}
```

My template just tries to output the events variable in json format

```
<p>
    {{
        events | json
    }}
</p>
```

As you can see I'm assigning the value of events to a local variable in a zone.run() callback. Still not seeing my template update. I've also tried ApplicationRef.tick and ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() but neither seem to detect my changes.

Console.log call does confirm that the data was updated. Any click handler fired on this component also seems to update the view.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Did I post enough of the code to get some advice? Let me know what else you would like to see.

Comment: Pretty minimal @StefanSvrkota but there you go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seed was setting the ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush. Setting this to default solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, assuming you haven't assigned a value to `this.events` before calling `getEventList()` method:

```
<div *ngIf="events">
{{ events | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had been assigning it an empty array as a value but even without that your suggestion didn't help.

Comment: I just tested your code without `this.zone.run` and it works like a charm. Like this: `ngOnInit(){
    this.eventService.getEventList()
        .subscribe(events => {
                this.events = events;
                console.log(this.events)
        });
}`

Comment: It works even with this.zone.run, I just tried it. Don't know what cause problem on your end. Maybe replicate your code on plunker then post it here.

Comment: Well if the problem isn' here it's likely something hiding in the seed I used to get my project started. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: This definitely helped me figure out my issue. Thanks for your help! I wish I could at least upvote this answer.